# Fast alternative to drawInRect

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

What is the fastest way to render and scale an image to a surface at a high frame rate?

I am drawing (with scaling) an NSBitmapImageRep using drawRect at ~30FPS but it uses a huge amount of CPU.

Sample code to set pixels in the NSBitmapImageRep at 30FPS:

```
NSInteger x, y;
unsigned char *imgptr = nsBitmapImageRepObj.bitmapData;
unsigned char *ptr;
NSInteger rowBytes = nsBitmapImageRepObj.bytesPerRow;

for (y = 0; y < nsInputFrameRect.size.height; y++) {
    ptr = imgptr + (y * rowBytes);
    for (x = 0; x < nsInputFrameRect.size.width; x++) {
        *ptr++ = 1; // R
        *ptr++ = 2; // G
        *ptr++ = 3; // B
    }

}
[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

The draw happening at 30FPS:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)pRect {
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];    
    [nsBitmapImageRepObj drawInRect:pRect];
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];    
} // end drawRect
```

drawInRect on the NSBitmapImageRep uses a lot of CPU. What is the fastest way of scaling and painting an image at a high frame rate? The source image should be an image for which I can set the pixels directly e.g. via getting a bitmapData pointer.

If I convert the NSBitmapImageRep to a CIImage and draw using [ciImage drawInRect] then it's about 10% faster. If I draw to an NSOpenGLView instead of an NSView it's about 10% faster again, but still the scale/drawInRect takes up a lot of CPU time.

Comment: Are you trying to color each pixel based on a formula?  This kind of operation would best be suited for the GPU.  Depending on what exactly you're tying to do, your solution could range from OpenGL shaders to CoreImage to even just Quartz.

Comment: It's for simple karaoke graphics but it's not formulaic: I update a low resolution NSBitmapImageRep image and then scale that small image up to the screen size at about 30FPS. Setting the pixels in the small NSBitmapImageRep is very fast but the regular scaling up of the image to screen size using drawInRect is very slow. Is it faster to upscale a CIImage? Or is there some faster way of scaling images when the source images can be set on a pixel-by-pixel basis?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should remove saving and restoring the `NSGraphicsContext`, because the `-[NSImageRep drawInRect:]` method does this itself . See "Cocoa Drawing Graphics Context":

```
Important: Saving and restoring the current graphics state is a relatively expensive operation that should done as little as possible.
```

Next point is the structure of your pixel data: 8 bit per sample and 3 samples per pixel which means 24 bits per pixel. This is very hardware(GPU?) unfriendly because 32 bit values are faster to handle than 24 bit values. There is a simple way to make pixel handling nicer (faster): use 4 bytes instead of 3: add a padding byte to each pixel, which does not harm the image! This padding byte is not part of the image but only part of the storage the pixel is stored in and is not used in any drawing operation. It is simply here to make pixel operations faster. So use this in the description of your `NSBitImageRep`:

```
bitsPerSample:8
samplesPerPixel:3
hasAlpha:NO
isPlanar:NO    // must be meshed
bytesPerRow:0  // let the system do it
bitsPerPixel:32   // <-- important !!
```

And therefore your code has to be modified:

```
    *ptr++ = 3; // B
    *ptr++ = 123; // new!! value is unimportant
```

BTW: if you read a jpeg-image into an `NSBitmapImageRep` then these imageReps always have  3-byte pixels plus a padding byte. Why this waste of storage? There are good reasons to do so!

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the context save and moved to 32bpp. That makes a lot of sense but 32bpp didn't make a noticeable difference to performance in my case. Scaling up from 200x200 to 400x400 takes about 7% CPU, but scaling up to about 1600x1600 takes 34% CPU, which appears to be all in the drawInRect() call. Perhaps NSBitmapImageRep drawInRect is not using the GPU for me. Is it more appropriate to use a CIImage to ensure it's handled by the GPU?